# How can I display my api response when user Login?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm getting responses from server correctly, when user login. How can I display those responses in my app
[image]

Here is my API service

```
     Future<void> login() async {
var jsonResponse = null;

if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  List user;
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/login"),
      body: ({
        'LoginId': emailController.text,
        'Password': passwordontroller.text
      }));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    print(jsonResponse);
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second()));
  } else {
    print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    print(response.body);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid credentials")));
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Blank field is not allowed")));
}
}
```

And now I want to print the response  `status code` `message` in my second page[image]

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code. Copy-paste the text of your code into the question itself. The same goes for that JSON api response in that first screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend serializing the API response to a dart class something like this :

```dart
class ApiResponse {
    ApiResponse({
        this.status,
        this.message,
        this.userData,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    UserData userData;

    factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ApiResponse(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        userData: UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]),
    );


}

class UserData {
    UserData({
        this.name,
        this.encUserId,
    });

    String name;
    String encUserId;

    factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
        name: json["Name"],
        encUserId: json["EncUserId"],
    );

}
```

So now you can have an ApiResponse type variable named "response" to SecondPage(), and navigate there by passing it like this :

```dart
Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second(response: ApiResponse.fromJson(response.data)));
```

Comment: Thats definitely  helpful. I created a new dart file where I put the `ApiResponse` & the `UserData` class, but when I'm navigating its still showing error here==> `Second(response: ApiResponse.fromMap(response.data` its showing `1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.` Also put I whole code below, can you help?

Comment: @KinkarRoy Have you also changed the `SecondPage` to include the `response` field?

Comment: No, in `secondPage` do I have to do like this?  `final status = response["Status"];
final message = response["Message"];`

Comment: First of, the method is `fromJson` not `fromMap` it was my typo I've editted it.

At `SecondPage` you will declare a `final ApiResponse response` and you should include a class constructor `const SecondPage({this.response});` and you're good to go.

Comment: In SecondPage i do like this:  `Class Second extends StatefulWidget {
  final ApiResponse response;
  const Second({required this.response});`  after that in body im printing like this=>` Text("Message: ${responseRef['Message']}"),`   But its still showing error in `main.dart` under `data` : `Second(response: ApiResponse.fromJson(response.data)));`

Comment: No, you access the serialized response like this:
`Text('Message: ${widget.response.message}')`

Comment: why in `main.dart` `Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second(response: ApiResponse.fromJson(response.data)));` its still showing `The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Response'.
Try importing the library that defines 'data', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data'.`  what is this data actually?

Comment: Try `response.body`. I usually use `Dio` package and the response from Dio requests have the `data` field.

Comment: I did try it before `response.body` its showing `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' `

Comment: I took a variable  `jsonResponse` and decode it to string ` jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());`  hope now its work

Comment: Good job and have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:try13/ApiResponse.dart';
import 'package:try13/second.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordontroller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller:
                    emailController, //==========================================
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Email",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller:
                    passwordontroller, //=========================================
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Password",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.password)),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 45,
              ),
              OutlinedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                   login() ;
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.login,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                  label: Text("Login"),
                  
                  ),
               
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  // CREATING FUNCTION TO CALL LOGIN API
  Future<void> login() async {
    var jsonResponse = null;
    if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/login"),
          body: ({
            'LoginId': emailController.text,
            'Password': passwordontroller.text
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Correct");
        print(response.body);
        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        print(jsonResponse);
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Second(response: ApiResponse.fromMap(response.data)));
      } else {
        print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
        print(response.body);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid credentials")));
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Blank field is not allowed")));
    }
  }




  
}
```